# multiline grid extjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, grid, multiline

i am newbie to Ext Js..i am working on ruby on rails...
can any1 suggest a good basic tutorial for "multiline grid" pllzz...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess for that you will have to return prepared data on the server and then add some css to it.

If you have one column then your data might look something like this:

```
<div> id and name </div>
<div> desc and pic </div>
```

Then add css for grid cells:

```
.x-grid3-cell-inner div { .... }
```

Would help if you posted an example.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

1. [extjs-multi-line-grid-headers-and-cells](http://dashasalo.wordpress.com/2011/04/01/extjs-multi-line-grid-headers-and-cells/)
2. [ext-js-grid-with-multiline-rows](http://babel.jorgebg.com/ext-js-grid-with-multiline-rows)

Comment: thanx...i went thru the suggested site, but i was wondering if there's some way wherein i can display grid in a way that for eg : first row contains id, name and second row contains desc n pic, and both the rows are treated as 1 tupple ?

Comment: @Shurti: You can modify CSS to get what you want.

Comment: can u plzz guide me in detail as to what changes are to be made in css??